# keywords missing after install robotframework-autoitlibrary

Tags: robotframework

I followed the steps below to install robotframework-autoitlibrary

1. Open cmd in "Run as administrator" mode
2. run the command pip install robotframework-autoitlibrary
3. Now clone the autoit library source code: nokia/robotframework-autoitlibrary.
4. in the root directory run the below command: python setup.py install using cmd as admin

but after it installed many keyword are missing , only few keywords from autoit library that I can use are below, how can i get full keywords library available ?

[image]